# setting the onclick value from <script> doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, getelementbyid

I have created a button in HTML 
`<button id = "back_button" type="button" onclick="" value="Home">Go Back</button>`
And have the code in the `<script>` tag
`document.getElementById("back_button").onclick = "redirect('" + previous_location + "')"`

If I set that manually in the HTML it works fine, but when set via the script it doesn't even run the function. I put a `console.log` to check and there was no output in the inspect element console or main

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or how I can change the value of the location of the button another way?

Comment: I think you meant `document.getElementById("back_button").onclick = () => redirect('" + previous_location + "')`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either
Edit; That did work, i just didn't remove the quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign callback from the script, you must provide a function variable, not a string:

```js
document.getElementById("back_button").onclick = redirect(previous_location)
```

But like this we would assign the result of `redirect` to the `onclick`, which should be a function. So create an anonymous function which calls redirect for you:

```js
document.getElementById("back_button").onclick = function() { redirect(previous_location); }
// OR
document.getElementById("back_button").onclick = () => redirect(previous_location);
```